# what is the meaning of use two bracket in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change the date format in javaScript and I find this code of "Mike Christensen" that is very nice.
But my question is about what is meaning of use two bracket in javascript array code at ***var month line 3***.

```
var mydate = new Date(form.startDate.value);
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]    [mydate.getMonth()];
var str = month + ' ' + mydate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: you are with that saving a couple of lines init the var month directly...

Comment: Consider accepting one of the answers if it is of any help

Answer (score 2):

He is indexing the month array using the month number that he gets it from mydate.getMonth()

Here in this code ,mydate.getMonth() is 11 and as is he indexing month array month[11] would be december

```js
var mydate = new Date();
console.log(mydate.getMonth());
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]    [mydate.getMonth()];
console.log(month);
var str = month + ' ' + mydate.getFullYear();
```

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

The first pair of brackets is creating of array, consider it like this

```
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

The next pair of brackets is a retrieving operation for the array by index.

```
someArr[index]
```

in your case

```
month[11]
```

That's it, the author just take an element of the just created array by index, where index is extracted from another variable.

Answer (score 0):

doing this: is  a very cheap way to init the var month with only elements in the array declared previously...(something that will save you to write one line more but IMHO decrease the readability of the code... )
so breaking that down:

```
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]    [mydate.getMonth()];
```

is the same as

```
var monthOptionsArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var monthIndex =  mydate.getMonth();
var monthActual =  monthOptionsArray[monthIndex];
```

## Example:

```js
var mydate = new Date();
console.log(mydate.getMonth());
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];    monthI = month[1];
console.log(monthI);
var str = month + ' ' + mydate.getFullYear();
```